# Plone upgrade from Ubuntu 8.04 to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: plone, zope

I'm having some difficulty upgrading my Plone install to 4.2.5.
The old Plone/zope install was running on Ubuntu 8.04.  I upgraded the OS to 12.04, and reinstalled plone and zope.

I followed the instructions at:  http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/minor-version-upgrades  for the upgrade.

The 12.04 install was successful, the trouble comes when I copy my old configs, and data over into the new install.

When I run bin/buildout after copying over, I get the message:

---

Error: Buildout now includes 'buildout-versions' (and part of the older 'buildout.dumppickedversions').
Remove the extension from your configuration and look at the 'show-picked-versions' option in buildout's documentation.

---

I tried removing the extensions, which allows bin/buildout to finish without error, however when I start zope, I get the following error:

---

File "/home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/persistent/**init**.py", line 19, in 
    from cPersistence import Persistent, GHOST, UPTODATE, CHANGED, STICKY
ImportError: /home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/persistent/cPersistence.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString

---

Answer (score 5):

Python comes in two Unicode flavours; narrow and wide, or UCS2 and UCS4, with wide builds allowing for more Unicode character support.  Your compiled C extension is compiled with a wide Python but you are now using a narrow Python.

Your best bet is to remove the ZODB3 egg and have buildout recreate it. Delete the /home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg directory altogether.

You probably have to do this for more eggs that have extensions.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give this a shot and report back.

Comment: Your explanation helped to also resolve this error: `ImportError: /home/ida/.buildout/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/persistent/cPersistence.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, thanks!

Comment: BTW, what worked for me was to delete all eggs which contain `x86_64` in their name.